# How to create multi-page working-set wizards

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, working-set

I'm developing an Eclipse Plug-in that is working with custom working sets. Right now the user can create those working-sets by starting a multi-page wizard via `File > New > Other... > Custom Working Set`.

By default, working-sets can also be created through the working-set selection dialog via `Project Explorer > Select Working Set... > New`. Those working set "wizards" (e.g. `Java` `Working-Set`, `Resource` `Working-Set`, ...) all consist of a single page. Technically there is a next button, but it's disabled after working-set type selection.

Is there any way to override that behavior to enable multi-page wizards? I believe that I have to work with the `WorkingSetNewWizard` class or with the `IWorkingSetNewWizard` interface, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get this thing working!

Just as greg-449 pointed out, adding a custom working-set can be accomplished by defining it at the extension point `org.eclipse.ui.workingSets` and implementing a page class that extends "WizardPage" implements `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.IWorkingSetPage`.

The class that's handling the working-set creation is `WorkingSetNewWizard`. By default, it creates a wizard that consists of two pages - the working-set type selection and the defined working-set page, corresponding to the selection of the user (That's why there is a `Next` button in that GUI).

To add another page, you have to override `WizardPage.getNextPage` (Thanks again to greg-449) in this page class. Passing the desired page does not work out of the box, because you have to add the creation wizard to the new `IWizardPage`:

```
@Override
public IWizardPage getNextPage() {
    IWizardPage page = new WizardPage2();
    page.setWizard(getWizard());
    return page;
}
```

Doing it this way, the second page does not have to implement IWorkingSetPage, because pressing the finish button will trigger the `finish()` function of the first page.

Answer (score 1):

The `workingSet` element of the `org.eclipse.ui.workingSets` extension point used for defining a new working set type has a `pageClass` attribute which is used to specify the class implementing the second page of the new working set wizard.

The page class must implement `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.IWorkingSetPage`.

The example in the Eclipse help:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.workingSets">
    <workingSet
        id="org.eclipse.ui.resourceWorkingSetPage"
        name="Resource"
        description="Contains basic resources (files, folders, and projects)"
        icon="icons/resworkset.png"
        pageClass="org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.ResourceWorkingSetPage"
        updaterClass="org.eclipse.ui.internal.workingsets.ResourceWorkingSetUpdater"
        elementAdapterClass="org.eclipse.ui.internal.workingsets.ResourceWorkingSetElementAdapter">
    </workingSet>
 </extension>
```

Note: `WorkingSetNewWizard` is an **internal** class so you must not reference it in your code.

Comment: I already managed to define a `pageClass`, but is it someway possible to add even more pages than just one? The definition of the working set can be done on the first page, but I have additional settings (pages) I would like to add to the wizard. I've already done this with the `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` extension point, implementing INewWizard, but now I wanted to add similar pages to the working-set dialog.

Comment: You could try overriding `WizardPage.getNextPage` on your page but I have no idea if it will work.

Comment: yes, I just tried that and it enables the next button, but now I have to figure out how to display a new page because now I'm getting a NullPointer at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.setWizard(WizardDialog.java:1173), but thanks again for your help!